# Route Model Binding in Relationships

Tags: forms, laravel, eloquent

A `store has many products` is the relationship.

How to create new product, saves store_id and other product details.

The code as below.

Route is

```
Route::resource('stores.product', 'productcontroller');
```

i.e. binding model store with product route.

Model `Store`

```
class store extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(product::class);
    }
}
```

`create product` View.

```
<form method="POST" action="/stores/{{$store->id}}/product" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        name  <input type="text" name="name" />
    </div>
```

`productController@store`

```
public function store ( store $store, Request $request )
{
     $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
         'detail' => 'nullable' ,
    ]);

    $product = new product;
    $product-> user_id = auth()->id();
    $product-> store_id = $store->id;
    $product-> name = $request->name;
    $product->save();
    return redirect('/stores/{{$store->id}}/product');
}
```

Please explain how route model binding works in relationships.

What should be my create form's method and action?

Where should `productController@store` return redirect?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create the inverse relation between stores and products
Like this:

```php
class Store extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{
    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belonsTo(Store::class);
    }
}
```

Second you have to pass all your stores to your create product page:

```php
public function create (){
    $storList = Store::all();
    return view("createproductview", compact("storList"));
}
```

In that page you have to show the stores to select one of them, and manage your errors from the validation process:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{ route("product.store") }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group {{ ($errors->has('store'))?"has-error":"" }}">
        <label for="store">Store</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="tipoaudiencia" id="store">
            <option value="">Select one option</option>
            @foreach($storList as $row)
                <option {{ (old("store") == $row->id ? "selected":"") }} value="{{ $row->id }}">{{ $row->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        @if($errors->has('store'))<p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('store') }}</p>@endif
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required {{ ($errors->has('name'))?"has-error":"" }}">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" autofocus>
        @if($errors->has('name'))<p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</p>@endif
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

and last the store function:

```php
public function store ( Request $request )
{
     $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'store' => 'required'
    ]);

    $product = new Product;
    $product->name = $request->name;
    $store = Store::find($request->store);
    $store->products()->save($product);//this saves the product and manage the relation.
    return redirect('/stores/'.$store->id.'/'.$product->id);
}
```

Hope this help you